# Large number of unmanagable groups in Exchange 2010 following migration from Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, exchange-migration

Recently we migrated from Exchange 2003 to 2010, and now we have many groups greyed out in the 2010 Exchange Management Console, because they are not Universal Groups. While these groups are unmanageable, we cannot shut down 2003 server.

We know that you can right-click and convert them to Universal, but as you may know, to be able to convert a group, you must convert all their parents.

The problem is that we have **so many** groups with **so many** parents, that if we convert all of them we will probably have problems with token size.

Anyone know how to get these groups converted?

Answer (score 0):

[You're experiencing the issue with Global Groups created in Exchange 2003 (or earlier) not being manageable](http://blogs.interfacett.com/why-are-my-exchange-distribution-group-properties-greyed-out-in-emc).

The solution is to use PowerShell (through the Exchange Management Shell).  [Run the following command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfodel/archive/2008/08/04/need-to-convert-global-groups-to-universal-groups.aspx):

> Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | where { $_.Grouptype -Like "Global*" } | Set-Group -Universal

You could also just select all of them in the Exchange Management Console and convert them... that works too. Either way you do it will probably take a long time to complete, and posiibly require more than one pass to convert all the groups (if it errors out on a nested group), but it will work and convert all the groups eventually. I've done a lot of Exchange migrations, including for a large multi-national with a very big Exchange environment, and PowerShell has never let me down.